# iOS 7 navigationbar barTintColor - able to have it fade from top to bottom?

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationbar

In `iOS7` the `navigation barTintColor` is very 'bland'.  In `iOS6` (and below) the color of the navigation bar would fade from lighter to darker from top to bottom.

In `iOS7`, I can make the navbar a custom color, but it is the same from top to bottom.  Is there any way to get the same fading effect?

Thank You!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the open-source [`CRGradientNavigationBar`](https://github.com/chroman/CRGradientNavigationBar) subclass to support gradients. This is preferable because it is more robust than having to deal with images.

[image]

You set up your navigation controller like so:

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithNavigationBarClass:[CRGradientNavigationBar class] toolbarClass:nil];
```

or set the class of the navigation bar in storyboard, and then pass an array of colors using `setBarTintGradientColors:`.

```
[[CRGradientNavigationBar appearance] setBarTintGradientColors:colors];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the various `UINavigationBar setBackgroundImage...` methods. Pass in an image with the desired gradient.

Keep in mind however, that people expect to see the new iOS 7 look in their iOS 7 app. This means moving away from the old iOS 6 look.

Comment: As I said, you should just use the modern iOS 7 look - no gradient.